# Settings API - save an array of options as one setting (array_push?)

Tags: options, array, settings-api

### 1. Basic settings API callback.

Using [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) my [$sanitize_callback](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) validating function looks like:

```
    (...)
    if($type == "foo") {
       $valid_input[$id] = $option[$id];
    }  

    else if($type == "bar") {
       $valid_input[$id] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($input[$id]);
    } 
    (...)
```

It's almost the same as in this great theme by Chip Bennett: https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/options-register.php#L95

### 2. Avoiding option updating.

After form submit all options are being updated and it's values are being overwritten with $input.

What if I don't want to update one of them (let's say it's `$type` is `multiple_settings`) but instead create an array and add new options to it? How do I do that?

I was trying things like:

```
    else if($type == "multiple_settings") {
       $valid_input[$id][] = $input[$id]; // creates an array but still overwrites
       $valid_input[$id] = array_push($valid_input[$id], $input[$id]); //returns NULL
     }
```

With no luck.

**[edit]**

Maybe it has something to do with the way I save my settings (return of validation function below)?

```
    $options = get_option('XX_theme_settings'); 
    $valid = array_merge($options,$valid_input);
    return $valid;
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I've understood correctly you essentially want an option whose value is an array, and you want to add to that array instead of replacing it? So if the value is `array('a','b')` and you recieve 'c' in your input you want the new value to be `array('a','b','c')`?

Comment: Stephen Harris, exactly! :) `$valid_input[$id][] = 'old option'; $valid_input[$id][] = 'newer option'; $valid_input[$id][] = 'latest option';` outputs exactly what I want, but no idea how to use it with $input! :) I believe it should work just fine as `$valid_input[$id][] = $input[$id];` but it doesn't.

Comment: Do you mind me asking why? Might help with a solution. If you do the above you can then never remove values, but only add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always develop with `WP_DEBUG` set to `TRUE`. You've a typo:

```
array_push($valid_input[$id], $input[$id];
```

(missing `)` after the `array_push`)

---

You can't push to arrays that are not ... arrays.

```
// So, check this before pushing: 
$valid_input[$id] = ! is_array( $valid_input[$id] ) ? (array) $valid_input[$id] : $valid_input[$id];
```

Comment: Sorry, but I made this typo here on stackexchange. By the way I believe this mistake will output `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` anyways. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @Wordpressor See update

Comment: It still returns NULL as well as `$valid_input[$id] = array();
$valid_input[$id] =   array_push($valid_input[$id], $input[$id]);`. Check the update above.